# Oracle gives error Message on prompt refresh

Tags: oracle11g, obiee

I'm relatively new to Oracle OBIEE (I'm using 11g) so bear with me as I attempt to describe this issue badly!

I have an direct database request that pulls data - in the where clause of the code, I use a presentation variable to get the query to pull certain data. The presentation variable is a prompt on my dashboard, alongside my direct database request.

When I edit the dashboard, edit the analysis, save it and then return to the dashboard, it shows data pulling correctly. When I refresh the prompt without changing anything, it then gives me this error:

State: HY000. Code: 10058. [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. [nQSError: 43119] Query Failed: [nQSError: 17001] Oracle Error code: 1830, message: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string at OCI call OCIStmtFetch. [nQSError: 17012] Bulk fetch failed. (HY000)

The prompt contains the same value, so I'm confused as to why it works when I first load the page, but won't when I click apply on the prompt without changing the value in the prompt.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

a) If you are new to OBI and immediately using direct database requests, then you are most definitely on the wrong way!
b) "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string" That's a pure code error and has nothing to do with OBI. Your SQL code is wrong with regards to how your DB is set up for date management.
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01830.php